# 10.4.2 401 Unauthorized error on 12C SB console

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper, weblogic12c, osb, soa-suite

I have just installed Oracle SOA Suite 12.1.3.0.0. 
Have created the integrated server and standalone server.

**Problem :** I'm not able to login to sbconsole.As soon as I hit enter after giving the userName/password, all I see is -

---

**Error 401--Unauthorized
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.2 401 Unauthorized**

The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.46) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the prior response, and the user agent has already attempted authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the entity that was given in the response, since that entity MAY include relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is explained in section 11.

---

Although, I'm able to login to weblogic and em with same credential.
Same behavior is observed in standalone and integrated server.

Any thoughts ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the em console does SOA_INFRA and Service bus show?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to see both in em. SOA --> service-bus and SOA--> soa-infra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [known login issues](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3619387) when using JDK8 with OSB. Is that the JDK that you're using? If so, rolling back to a supported JDK (JDK 1.7.0_55+) might fix things.

Comment: Thanks Trent. The link was useful.I pointed the JAVA_HOME to jdk1.7.0_55, but the jdeveloper was not able to pick this change, as Oracle hardcode the Java_HOME value
in config files.So,I decided to replace JAVA_HOME value in all files inside ORACLE_HOME (Notepad++ helped me here).After this also jdev was not able to pick new JAVA_HOME.
So, I decided to re-install soa-suite, which of-course resolved the issue.
Later, when I deleted JDEV_USER_HOME, I realized, jdev might have stored the old JAVA_HOME(java1.8) here. Not sure !

Answer (score 0):

Configuring your WL server domain with JDK 1.7.0_5 will also work.

i.e Point your **SUN_JAVA_HOME** & **DEFAULT_SUN_JAVA_HOME** to **jdk1.7.0_79** in 
*%Domain%\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd* & restart server

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by using an incorrect JDK version.

JDK 1.8 / 8 is not certified for Oracle SOA Suite 12c 12.1.3.

**Please Note: you must install above soa suite jars using JDK 1.7 , because if you install it using JDK 1.8 and even if you replace the jdk version in MIDDLEWARE_HOME config. files will not work.**